# Is there a way to use ? : notation without assignment / with methods returning void

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-operator

Is there a way to use ? : notation in c# without assigning result of the expression, or even with expressions, after ? operator, which do not return any values.

E.g. I want to run something like it

```
(1=1) ? errorProvider.SetError(control,"Message") : DoNothing();

expression? DoSomething (): DoSomethingElese()
```

where DoSomething and DoSomethingElse returns types are void.

Comment: Why? You can always use `if (expression) DoSomething(); else DoSomethingElese();`.

Comment: Yes however I was wandering whether there is some way to hack it.

Comment: Is this another try to shorten code in a couple of lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`?:` returns a value based upon a `boolean` condition.  You can't use `void` in the 
expression.

Just use `if`

```
   if (expression) {
        DoSomething();
   } else {
        DoSomethingElse();
   }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

No. The whole point of the ternary operator is that it returns something. In other words: the expression must have a return type (other than `void`). In this case, you just need to use an `if`/`else` construction.

Answer (score 2):

Closest you can get is by extending the boolean type:

```
public static void IIF(this bool condition, Action doWhenTrue, Action doWhenFalse)
{
    if (condition)
        doWhenTrue();
    else
        doWhenFalse();
}
```

Then you win a oneliner:

```
(1 == 1).IIF(() => DoSomething(), () => DoSomethingElse());
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can't - an If/Else would be the right choice.  In your example though, you could do something like:

```
errorProvider.SetError(control, SomeCondition ? "Message" : string.Empty)
```